# Volley request: can't load markers on map fragment programmatically on start - JSONException: Index 3 out of range [0..3)

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Im working on a Map based APP and need to get markers from JSON to load on start on map fragment, my idea is to load all makers programmatically on start and hide it, the hide method works fine but the volley request throws an exception. i'm currently using volley library and after to many tutorials got this method:

```
private void markerRequest(){

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
    (Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("markers");

                for (int i = 0; 1 < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject markers = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = markers.getString("id");
                    LatLng[0] = markers.getDouble("latitud");
                    LatLng[1] = markers.getDouble("longitud");
                    String address = markers.getString("direccion");
                    String category = markers.getString("categoria");
                    String detail = markers.getString("detalle_tipo");
                    FirstRunSetMarker(new LatLng(LatLng[0], LatLng[1]), detail, address, category, id);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("VOLLEY ERROR: ","" + error);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    });

    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
}
```

so i'm calling "markerRequest();" on onCreateView method (also tryied on onMapReady method). The JSONObject that i'm calling and parsing is this:

```
    {
    "markers":[
        {
        "id":"1",
        "direccion":"Las Fucsias 3510",
        "latitud":"-33.3916",
        "longitud":"-70.6951",
        "estrellas":"3",
        "categoria":"1",
        "detalle_cat":"Gastronomia",
        "tipo":"1",
        "detalle_tipo":"Restaurante"
        },
        {
        "id":"2",
        "direccion":"Longitudinal Seis 656",
        "latitud":"-33.4156",
        "longitud":"-70.6734",
        "estrellas":"4",
        "categoria":"2",
        "detalle_cat":"Deportes",
        "tipo":"2",
        "detalle_tipo":"Ciclismo"
        },
        {
        "id":"3",
        "direccion":"Los Leones 1-119",
        "latitud":"-33.4207",
        "longitud":"-70.6061",
        "estrellas":"5",
        "categoria":"3",
        "detalle_cat":"Pasa Tiempo",
        "tipo":"3",
        "detalle_tipo":"Video Juego"
        }
        ]
    }
```

Just in case the singleton class is this:

```
private MySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
}

public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}}
```

so when map fragment start i'm getting this error:

```
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Index 3 out of range [0..3)
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err:     at   org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:293)
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:521)
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err:     at com.lookingfor.hotelappv1.Fragments.MapsFragment$9.onResponse(MapsFragment.java:612)
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err:     at com.lookingfor.hotelappv1.Fragments.MapsFragment$9.onResponse(MapsFragment.java:603)
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
05-15 19:20:33.980 2238-2238/com.lookingfor.hotelappv1 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

i don't know what i'm doing wrong, already tried to call the request from async task and other methods. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; 1 < jsonArray.length(); i++)`. I'm guessing `1` is a typo there and needs to be replaced with `i`.

Comment: i didn't see that "1" in the code, that was making me crazy, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your code and found the bug...! It is not the problem of the `markers`, the problem lies in the iteration (for loop), replace your onResponse method with the below method,

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("markers");

            for (int i = 0; 1 < jsonArray.length(); i++){    // This line causes the exception
                JSONObject markers = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = markers.getString("id");
                LatLng[0] = markers.getDouble("latitud");
                LatLng[1] = markers.getDouble("longitud");
                String address = markers.getString("direccion");
                String category = markers.getString("categoria");
                String detail = markers.getString("detalle_tipo");
                FirstRunSetMarker(new LatLng(LatLng[0], LatLng[1]), detail, address, category, id);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

**Issue:**
The issue is your loop work infinite times which produces the `JSONException` basically it is an `ArrayOutOfBoundException`